# Need help in understanding texas holdem game

Tags: java, algorithm

In texas holdem there are two 7 cards, two hole cards and 5 cards on the table for a player. Can someone please point out the algorithm for determining the hand evaluation for a player(how it needs to be done). I have created two list

```
List<Card> holeCards = new Arraylist(); // 2S 5H two cards for a player
List<Card> cardsOnTable = new Arraylist(); // 6C AS 5C 7D 6D cards on table
List <Card> allCards = new Arraylist();
allCards.addall(holeCards);
allCards.addall(cardsOnTable); // AS 7D 6C 6D 5C 5H 2S -- after sorting cards in descending order
```

How should i pick first five cards from the sorted list to determine a hand evaluator. i have gone through some example of texas holdem poker but i am not able to clearly understand how to approach this problem

Answer (score 2):

You can't immediately eliminate 2 cards, the lowest 5 cards could make a flush, whilst the highest one a full house.

Personally I would evaluate for each type of hand from the 7 cards (hand plus 5 cardsOnTable)

Start with the highest ranking first (Straigh flush, which means you can check straight and flush whilst your at it), (You can improve each of these methods to improve speed later)

1. Check for Flush (cycle through the array, and count instances of each suit), if one hits 5, you have a flush
2. Check for Straight - sort the array in chronological order see if the next int in array follows on
3. Then make a histogram of all the cards, (check how many times each number appears)
   If you have 4,1,1,1 or 4,2,1 you have 4 of a kind
   3,2,1,1 or 3,2,2 you have a full house
   3,1,1,1,1 a set
   2,2,1,1,1 2 pair
   2,1,1,1,1,1 a pair
   1,1,1,1,1,1,1, high card

once you know what your best hand is you can pick you best 5 cards. Them compare this against another hand

Comment: Found this link, do it but with 7 cards. Use this to pick your best 5, then evaluate against opponents hand

http://nsayer.blogspot.com/2007/07/algorithm-for-evaluating-poker-hands.html